# docker-compoes.yml settings with Django + Gunicorn + NGINX does not work on `docker-compose up`

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

This is my folder structure.

```
./awesome_app
├── awesome_app
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── awesome_app_to_do_list
├── db.sqlite3
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── logs
│   ├── nginx-access.log
│   └── nginx-error.log
├── manage.py
├── nginx
│   └── nginx.conf
├── requirements.txt
├── run
└── start.sh
```

This is my nginx.conf.

```
upstream awesome_app {
    server unix:/home/notalentgeek/Downloads/awesome_app/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=10s;
}

server {
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    listen 8080;

    access_log /home/notalentgeek/Downloads/awesome_app/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/notalentgeek/Downloads/awesome_app/logs/nginx-error.log warn;

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias   /home/notalentgeek/Downloads/awesome_app/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://awesome_app;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my docker-compose.yml.

```
version: "3"  
services:  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx_awesome_app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./:/src
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: ./
    container_name: django_awesome_app
    volumes:
      - ./:/src
    expose:
      - "8080"
```

This is my start.sh.

```
#!/bin/bash

# PENDING: From the source here,
# http://tutos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/ndg.html it says that it is a
# common practice to have a specific user to handle the webserver.

SCRIPT=$(readlink -f "$0")
BASEDIR=$(dirname "$SCRIPT")
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=awesome_app.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=awesome_app.wsgi
NAME="awesome_app"
NUM_WORKERS=3

VENV_BIN=${BASEDIR}"/venv/bin"
SOCKFILE=${BASEDIR}"/run/gunicorn.sock"

echo $SOCKFILE

SOCKFILEDIR="$(dirname "$SOCKFILE")"
VENV_ACTIVATE=${VENV_BIN}"/activate"
VENV_GUNICORN=${VENV_BIN}"/gunicorn"

# Activate the virtual environment.
cd $BASEDIR
source $VENV_ACTIVATE
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$BASEDIR

# Create run directory if they does not exists.
test -d $SOCKFILEDIR || mkdir -p $SOCKFILEDIR

# Start Gunicorn!
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves
# (do not use --daemon).
exec ${VENV_GUNICORN} ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
    --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
    --name $NAME \
    --workers $NUM_WORKERS
```

Running through these commands.

- `docker-compose build`
- `docker-compose up -d`
- `docker-compose up`

Gives me these errors.

```
Starting django_awesome_app ... 
Starting django_awesome_app ... done
Starting nginx_awesome_app ... 
Starting nginx_awesome_app ... done
Attaching to django_awesome_app, nginx_awesome_app
django_awesome_app | //run/gunicorn.sock
django_awesome_app | /start.sh: line 25: //venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory
django_awesome_app | /start.sh: line 35: //venv/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory
nginx_awesome_app | 2017/09/27 17:21:31 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/home/notalentgeek/Downloads/awesome_app/logs/nginx-access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx_awesome_app | nginx: [emerg] open() "/home/notalentgeek/Downloads/awesome_app/logs/nginx-access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
django_awesome_app exited with code 127
nginx_awesome_app exited with code 1
```

I suppose there is something wrong in:

- How the `virtualenv` activated (or not activated at all).
- How the `volumes` transferred in docker-compose.yml.

Additionally, the message log is not detected when this goes to container because I still have `access_log /home/notalentgeek/Downloads/awesome_app/logs/nginx-access.log;` in my nginx.conf.

How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, your `nginx.conf` is referencing what looks like your host paths, and not container paths. The `nginx` service will not have `/home/notalentgeek/`.

You have not included your Dockerfile, but I imagine that the problem there is that virtualenv is not installed in the Dockerfile. That's why you get the error `/start.sh: line 25: //venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory`.

You may find working off an example will help to understand more how Docker specifically and containers in general work. Unfortunately, there have been a lot of changes to how Docker works and best-practices over the past few years, so many examples will have outdated information. It's best to read through several along with the official Docker documentation to piece together a working system. Looking through active Github projects can help, to see how open-source systems handle Docker.

I find the [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) project helpful for putting nginx in front of Docker containers. The README for the project has good instructions for using it as a drop-in to your `docker-compose.yml`. Using that container will handle the nginx side, and you will just need to fix up your Django app Dockerfile.

Comment: I will try to address the problems, one-by-one. Despite I have not yet installed the virtual environment in the container, I have already prepare the venv folder in my host. Does not this already solve my problem?

Comment: No, the container has its own isolated filesystem. You need to copy in both the `venv` folder as a volume, _and_ have the `virtualenv` package installed in the container image. Otherwise, there is nothing to run. To get an idea of what's happening, try setting `entrypoint: sleep 9999` in your `web` service, then running `docker-compose exec web /bin/bash` and poke around. You should see exactly what commands are installed, what files exist, etc.

Comment: I just try to `echo` from my start.sh to see what files are there in the container. It returns that I have all files necessary to launch the script. For example `/venv/bin/activate` is exists when I run `ls` from my start.sh. So can I just copy the whole project into the container? Is this a best practice or not?

Comment: I think your problem there is `VENV_BIN=${BASEDIR}"/venv/bin"`, where `BASEDIR=/`. So the final result is `//venv/bin` instead of `/venv/bin`. I think you still need to have `virtualenv` installed inside the container for that to work, though. I think there are also issues with changing the file paths, where the environment will be assuming `/home/notalentgeek` exists.